# Grid Showing old values after updation using ObjectDataSource to bind and Update the grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ObjectDataSource to Bind and update the grid .It is working fine and the records are updating in the database but after updating ,it is still showing the same records  in the grid (Previous Values). Please help me that what i will do so that after database updation, The grid will display updated records ,not the old records.Please modify my code also in case if any one found the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Please find the code below.

**GridView Code:-**

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGrdShift" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto" Width="900px" Height="520px" CssClass="srcColor">
            <cc1:GridView  ID="gvShift" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
               CssClass="grid"
               OnDataBound="gvShift_DataBound" 
               DataSourceID="odsShiftDetails" 
               AllowPaging="True" 
               ShowFooter="false"
               onrowcancelingedit="gvShift_RowCancelingEdit" 
               onrowcommand="gvShift_RowCommand" 
               onrowdeleting="gvShift_RowDeleting" 
               onrowediting="gvShift_RowEditing" 
               onrowupdating="gvShift_RowUpdating" 
               OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvShift_SelectedIndexChanged" 
               OnRowDataBound="gvShift_RowDataBound">        
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrowstyle"  />
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle" Wrap="false"  />
                <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="#edf5ff" Height="300px" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <EmptyDataTemplate >
                    No Records Found
                </EmptyDataTemplate> 
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="E Code" SortExpression="userecode" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibre" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserECode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("userecode") %>' CssClass="GridContent" />                    
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEditUserECode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("userecode") %>' style="width:50px;" CssClass="GridContent" />                    
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                       

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name" SortExpression="username" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibre" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("username") %>' CssClass="GridContent" />                    
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEditUserName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("username") %>' style="width:100px;" CssClass="GridContent"/>                    
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shift Start Time" SortExpression="ShiftStartTime" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibre" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblShiftStartTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ShiftStartTime") %>'  CssClass="GridContent"/>                    
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ddlShiftStartTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ShiftStartTime") %>' style="width:65px;" CssClass="GridContent" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpValidatorddlShiftStartTime" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlShiftStartTime" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ToolTip="Must be in HH:MM" />                            

                        </EditItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>  

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Shift End Time" SortExpression="ShiftEndTime" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibre" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblShiftEndTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ShiftEndTime") %>' CssClass="GridContent" />                    
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ddlShiftEndTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ShiftEndTime") %>' style="width:65px;" CssClass="GridContent"  />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpValidatorddlShiftEndTime" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlShiftEndTime" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ToolTip="Must be in HH:MM" />                            

                        </EditItemTemplate>                            
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="ShiftEndTIme" HeaderText="Shift End Time" SortExpression="ShiftEndTIme"/>--%>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saturday Shift Start Time" SortExpression="WeekendShiftStartTime" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibre" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblWeekendShiftStartTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("WeekendShiftStartTime") %>' CssClass="GridContent" />                    
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ddlWeekendShiftStartTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("WeekendShiftStartTime") %>' style="width:65px;" CssClass="GridContent" />  
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpValidatorddlWeekendShiftStartTime" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlWeekendShiftStartTime" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ToolTip="Must be in HH:MM" />                          

                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saturday Shift End Time" SortExpression="weekendshiftendtime" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibre" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblWeekendShiftEndTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("weekendshiftendtime") %>' CssClass="GridContent"/>                    
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ddlWeekendShiftEndTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("weekendshiftendtime") %>' style="width:65px;" CssClass="GridContent" /> 
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpValidatorddlWeekendShiftEndTime" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlWeekendShiftEndTime" ValidationExpression="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" ToolTip="Must be in HH:MM" />                           

                        </EditItemTemplate>                           
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField  ShowHeader="False" > 
                        <EditItemTemplate> 
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ForeColor="White"></asp:LinkButton> 
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ForeColor="White"></asp:LinkButton> 
                        </EditItemTemplate> 
                        <ItemTemplate> 
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" ForeColor="White"></asp:LinkButton> 
                        </ItemTemplate> 
                </asp:TemplateField>                    
           </Columns>
                <PagerTemplate >
                     <table width="100%" >
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:  left">
                                Page Size: 
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPageSize" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" style="width:50px;">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="10" ></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="20" ></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="30" ></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="40" ></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="50" ></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: right">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPageCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </PagerTemplate>
                </cc1:GridView>      
         </asp:Panel>


 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsShiftDetails" runat="server" 
                SelectMethod="GetShiftInfoSortedPage" TypeName="EQ.DAL.ShiftInfoDB"
                EnablePaging="True" SelectCountMethod="GetShiftInfoCount" 
                SortParameterName="sortExpression" UpdateMethod="UpdateShift">
                <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="sql"/>
                </UpdateParameters>
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter  ControlID="hfSearchCriteria"  Name="searchCriteria" Direction="Input"  />
                </SelectParameters>                                            
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**Code Behind for Update:-**

```
protected void gvShift_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TextBox txtShiftStartTime = (TextBox)gvShift.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlShiftStartTime");
            TextBox txtShiftEndTime = (TextBox)gvShift.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlShiftEndTime");
            TextBox txtWeekendShiftStartTime = (TextBox)gvShift.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlWeekendShiftStartTime");
            TextBox txtWeekendShiftEndTime = (TextBox)gvShift.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlWeekendShiftEndTime");
            Label lblUserecode = (Label)gvShift.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblEditUserECode");

            string userecode = lblUserecode.Text.ToString();
            string _ShiftStart = txtShiftStartTime.Text.ToString();
            string _ShiftEnd = txtShiftEndTime.Text.ToString();
            string _WeekendShiftStart = txtWeekendShiftStartTime.Text.ToString();
            string _WeekendShiftend = txtWeekendShiftEndTime.Text.ToString();

            EmployeeQuotientCL.Entities.ConfigurationVariables _configVariables = new ConfigurationVariables();
            string databaseConnectionString = _configVariables.ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
            if (((databaseConnectionString + string.Empty) != string.Empty))
            {

                DBConnect dbConnect = new DBConnect(_configVariables.ConnectionString);
                sqlConnection = dbConnect.SQLConnection;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = sqlConnection;
                string sql=null;
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE UserInfo SET ShiftStartTime ='" + _ShiftStart + "',ShiftEndTime='" + _ShiftEnd.ToString() + "',Weekendshiftstarttime='" + _WeekendShiftStart.ToString() + "',Weekendshiftendtime='" + _WeekendShiftend.ToString() + "'   WHERE UserECode=" + userecode.ToString();
                odsShiftDetails.UpdateParameters["sql"].DefaultValue = cmd.CommandText;
                odsShiftDetails.Update();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

**ShiftInfoDBCache.cs**

```
public class ShiftInfoDB
{
    private const string SHIFTINFO_CACHE_KEY = "SHIFTINFO_DATA";
    private const string SHIFTINFOCOUNT_CACHE_KEY = "SHIFTINFO_COUNT";
    static EmployeeQuotientCL.Entities.ConfigurationVariables _config = new EmployeeQuotientCL.Entities.ConfigurationVariables();
    static int _SupervisorecodeforShift;


    public static  DataTable GetShiftInfoSortedPage(int maximumRows, int startRowIndex, string sortExpression, string searchCriteria)
    {
        _SupervisorecodeforShift=EmployeeQuotientCL.Entities.StaticGlobalValue.UserId;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortExpression))
            sortExpression = "userecode";
        try
        {
            if (ShiftInfoDBCache.isRecordsCached(SHIFTINFO_CACHE_KEY))
                return ShiftInfoDBCache.GetData(SHIFTINFO_CACHE_KEY, startRowIndex + 1, maximumRows, sortExpression, searchCriteria);

            SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ToString());
            string sql = "select distinct MP.userecode,UI.username,UI.ShiftStartTime,UI.ShiftEndTime,UI.WeekendShiftStartTime,UI.weekendshiftendtime from AssociateSupervisorMapping MP inner join UserInfo UI on MP.Userecode=UI.Userecode where supervisorecode=" + _SupervisorecodeforShift.ToString();

            SqlCommand custCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);

            custCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(custCommand);
            DataTable dtCustomers = new DataTable();
            ad.Fill(dtCustomers);
            dbConnection.Close();


            //Cache records
            ShiftInfoDBCache.Add(SHIFTINFO_CACHE_KEY, dtCustomers);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return ShiftInfoDBCache.GetData(SHIFTINFO_CACHE_KEY, startRowIndex + 1, maximumRows, sortExpression, null);
    }

    public static int GetShiftInfoCount(string searchCriteria)
    {
         _SupervisorecodeforShift=EmployeeQuotientCL.Entities.StaticGlobalValue.UserId;
        int custCount = 0;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ToString());
            string sql = "select Count(*)from (select distinct MP.userecode,UI.username,UI.ShiftStartTime,UI.ShiftEndTime,UI.WeekendShiftStartTime,UI.weekendshiftendtime from AssociateSupervisorMapping MP inner join UserInfo UI on  MP.Userecode=UI.Userecode   where supervisorecode="+_SupervisorecodeforShift.ToString()+")AS internalQuery";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria))
                sql = sql + " where " + searchCriteria;

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);
            sqlCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
            dbConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            custCount = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());

            dbConnection.Close();

            if (ShiftInfoDBCache.Get(SHIFTINFOCOUNT_CACHE_KEY) != null)
            {
                // remove customers data if customers count has changed since first cache
                if (Convert.ToInt32(ShiftInfoDBCache.Get(SHIFTINFOCOUNT_CACHE_KEY)) != custCount && string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria))
                {
                    ShiftInfoDBCache.Remove(SHIFTINFO_CACHE_KEY);
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria))
                ShiftInfoDBCache.Add(SHIFTINFOCOUNT_CACHE_KEY, custCount);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return custCount;

    }

    public static void UpdateShift(string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.CommandText=sql;
        dbConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
        //sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConnection.Close();
    }



}
```

**ShiftInfoDBCache.cs**

```
public  class ShiftInfoDBCache
{
    public static bool isRecordsCached(string cacheKey)
    {
        Cache dbCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;

        if (dbCache[cacheKey] == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static void Add(string key, object value)
    {
        Cache dbCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;

        dbCache.Add(key, value, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

    }

    public static object Get(string key)
    {
        Cache dbCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;

        return dbCache[key];
    }

    public static object Remove(string key)
    {
        Cache dbCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;

        return dbCache.Remove(key);
    }

    public static DataTable GetData(string cacheKey, int startRowIndex, int maximumRowNumber, string sortExpression, string searchCriteria)
    {
        Cache dbCache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;

        if (dbCache[cacheKey] != null)
        {

            DataTable dtble = dbCache[cacheKey] as DataTable;
            DataTable dtblNew = dtble.Clone();

            DataRow[] rows = dtble.Select(searchCriteria, sortExpression);

            if (rows != null)
            {
                if (rows.Count() > 0)
                {
                    if (startRowIndex > rows.Count())
                    {
                        startRowIndex = rows.Count() - maximumRowNumber;

                        if (startRowIndex < 0)
                        {
                            startRowIndex = 1;
                            maximumRowNumber = rows.Count();
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = startRowIndex - 1; i < (startRowIndex + maximumRowNumber - 1); i++)
                    {
                        if (i < rows.Count())
                            dtblNew.ImportRow(rows[i]);
                    }

                    return dtblNew;
                }
            }

            return dtblNew;

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void UpdateShift(string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConnection);
        sqlCommand.CommandType=CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.CommandText=sql;
        dbConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
        //sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbConnection.Close();
        ShiftInfoDBCache.Remove(SHIFTINFO_CACHE_KEY);


    }
```

Modifying `UpdateShift` Method in `ShiftInfoDB.cs` fixed my issue.